# Reading XML file with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

**Summary:**

I know it's a long read. To summarize, I need the name, prefix and all values under every language that aren't in the `documentation` column. And I also need to store which language each label is attributed with.

**My problem is:**

Reading the data and keeping it with it's proper column - mainly if there is a *blank value*, it throws everything off. In the Excel example above, for the blank Japanese label, and following code will actually move `gl-plt` into the `label` column:

```
for(int t=0; t<labelLinkValues.Count; t+=labelLinkCol.Count) {

    for(int j=0; j<labelLinkCol.Count; j++) {
        if(labelLinkCol[j].Value=="prefix")
            Response.Write(labelLinkValues[t+j].Value+"<br/>");

        if(labelLinkCol[j].Value=="name")
            Response.Write(labelLinkValues[t+j].Value+"<br/>");

        for(int p=0; p<langList.Count; p++) {
            if(j>=langList[p].start&&j<=langList[p].end)
                if(labelLinkCol[j].Value!="documentation"&&labelLinkValues[j].Value!="")
                    Response.Write(langList[p].languageValue+"---"+labelLinkValues[t+j].Value+"<br/>");
        }

    }

    Response.Write("----<br>");
}
```

---

**The whole story:**

I am trying to read an **excel exported XML file** with Linq. I am able to get the data but I cannot make it work properly of aligning columns with the proper row cell.

Before I post the code I should mention some things. This program is designed to read **any number of files**, they may have **multiple languages**(the second row). In this particular example, there are two languages, but in the future there could be 1 language, 3 languages, e.g. The languages are defined as follows:

```
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="ColumnHead2" ss:Index="4" ss:MergeAcross="1">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">en</ss:Data>
    </Cell>

    <Cell ss:StyleID="ColumnHead2" ss:MergeAcross="1">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">ja</ss:Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
```

The index attribute of the first language tells you where it begins and the merge across tells you how many columns it spans. The subsequent languages only contain merge across values which tell you how many columns each language spans afterwards.

First of all, here is a screenshot of two rows of sample data.

> (the resolution is higher of downloded image)
>   [image]

And here is the corresponding XML code for the first row:

```
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderNumberCell">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">1</ss:Data>
    </Cell>

    <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">gl-cor</ss:Data>
    </Cell>

    <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">account</ss:Data>
    </Cell>

    <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Tuple: parent container for account numbers and identifiers. No entry is made here, but each detail line may have multiple accounts assigned to it for reporting in different GAAPs, offsetting accounts in Japan</ss:Data>
    </Cell>

    <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Account Identifier</ss:Data>
    </Cell>

    <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">タプル。勘定科目番号と識別子</ss:Data>
    </Cell>

    <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell"/>

    <Cell ss:StyleID="NoBorderCell">
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">gl-plt</ss:Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
```

There are 3 values that I need to extract from a given XML file:

Name and prefix, which are not part of the languages and are always present, getting them is not an issue.

Any value under a language column that does not say `documentation`. So I need to **ignore the `documentation` columns**.

Now here is the code I have, to read in the above:

```
XElement xdocument=XElement.Load(fpath);
XNamespace ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XNamespace docProperties="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office";
XNamespace ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XNamespace search="ss";

var labelLinkCol=(
    from worksheets in xdocument.Elements(ns+"Worksheet")
    where (string)worksheets.Attribute(ss+"Name")=="Label Link"
    from columnHead in worksheets.Descendants(ns+"Cell")
    where (string)columnHead.Attribute(ss+"StyleID")=="ColumnHead"
    select columnHead
    ).ToList();

var langValues=(
    from worksheets in xdocument.Elements(ns+"Worksheet")
    where (string)worksheets.Attribute(ss+"Name")=="Label Link"
    from columnHead in worksheets.Descendants(ns+"Cell")
    where (string)columnHead.Attribute(ss+"StyleID")=="ColumnHead2"
    select columnHead
    ).ToList();

var labelLinkValues=(
    from worksheets in xdocument.Elements(ns+"Worksheet")
    where (string)worksheets.Attribute(ss+"Name")=="Label Link"
    from columnHead in worksheets.Descendants(ns+"Cell")
    where
        (string)columnHead.Attribute(ss+"StyleID")!="ColumnHead"
        &&
        (string)columnHead.Attribute(ss+"StyleID")!="ColumnHead2"
        &&
        (string)columnHead.Attribute(ss+"StyleID")!="ColumnHead2BL"
    select columnHead
    ).ToList();

int index=0;
List<language> langList=new List<language>();

for(int j=0; j<langValues.Count; j++) {
    language languageXML=new language();

    //the first value has the index
    if(j==0) {
        index=Convert.ToInt32(langValues[j].Attribute(ss+"Index").Value);
        languageXML.index=index;
        languageXML.start=index;
        languageXML.end=index+Convert.ToInt32(langValues[j].Attribute(ss+"MergeAcross").Value);
        languageXML.languageValue=langValues[j].Value;
    }
    else {
        //get the value of when the first language begins
        languageXML.index=index;

        //to get the beginning, get the end of the previous location and add 1
        languageXML.start=langList[langList.Count-1].end+1;

        //to get the last column, add the merge to the beginning
        languageXML.end=languageXML.start+Convert.ToInt32(langValues[j].Attribute(ss+"MergeAcross").Value);
        languageXML.languageValue=langValues[j].Value;
    }

    langList.Add(languageXML);
    //Response.Write(languageXML.start + "--" + languageXML.end + "--" + languageXML.languageValue + "<br>");
}
```

`language` is a simple class that just contains the column of the first language, the starting column of the current language and the ending column of the current language.

I believe the above code as sound. It reads in all of the values and correctly identifies the starting and ending location for each language, and the problem is as described at the front of post.

Comment: This is a terrible XML format. Can't you get the data in some better format?

Comment: have you tried xsd.exe?  if you are just reading everything in, that might be a far easier way to go if it can parse properly

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way to get the data, it is given from a client who exports it from an excel worksheet to this.  The data is reading in pretty well, its just handling blanks that is killing me in the logic.

Comment: @jle my understanding of XSD is that its used for situations where you have an XML file and no schema?  For this kind of purpose the structure is mainly always intact just has differences in language.

Comment: xsd.exe is a visual studio dev tool that will create c# classes for you and then you can deserialize the XML into the c# strongly typed classes - http://dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2010/05/correctly-creating-classes-using-xsdexe.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're making it way more complex than it needs to be. I have recently worked on a project that required users to copy data from excel that is being read as a XML spreadsheet via the clipboard, that is then sent through a parser and transformed into a tabular format.

I found the XML Spreadsheet Reference invaluable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx

One thing you should be aware of and that I think is the cause of your problems is that the ss:Index isn't zero based (Column 1 = Index 1).

It should really be as simple as looping over the rows and then their cells and keeping track of a cells' index. You might also want to check whether the required cell does have a child data element.